# map old windows server to new windows server

Tags: internal-dns, hosts, netbios, mapping

At the moment, I have 2 servers (serve1 and serve2).
serve1 is old and data is small enough to move to serve2.

serve1 = Win 2k3
serve2 = Win 2008 R2

The problem is I need to keep the serve1 name active as it is in some physical documents that I'm told can't be changed.  I need to keep serve2 as serve2 as this is the primary file share and would disrupt many people if I change the netbios name.

So, bassically, what I need to do is map  serve1 to serve2 when someone enters the path.

ie:
¥¥serve1¥SharedDocs   ->   ¥¥serve2¥Shared_Documents

I imagine this will need to be done on my DNS (windows DNS services), but for now, I want to test locally via hosts file before editing DNS.

If someone could let me know how to do both the local hosts file and the DNS, that would be great.  I've been searching this a lot and can't find the right solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your local hosts file you can point serve1 name to serve2's IP address like this:
10.0.0.X      serve1

Then on serve2 create a new share name for the existing share, with serve1's share name like this:
\serve2\SharedDocs

This should allow when you type \serve1\SharedDocs to resolve to \serve2\Shared_Documents

For your DNS entry you will need to create an A record that points serve1 name to serve2 IP address.

Answer (score 2):

You can create two map drives either by going to group policy management or create a login script. In Group policy, Map drive configuration settings is located under  **user configuration/Preferences/Windows Settings/DriveMaps**. In here you can and add two shares:

\\Server1\ShareFolder

\\Server2\Sharefolder

To Create login script, open notepad and enter the command

**NET USE H: \\Server1\Sharefolder**

**NET USE U: \\Server2\sharefolder**

Save this as .bat extension and include this file in user's profile logon script

Answer (score 0):

you can create a login script that each drive will point to a different server.

logon.bat

NET USE G: \SERVER01\SHARE /PERSISTENT:NO

NET USE J: \SERVER02\SHARE /PERSISTENT:NO